# Difference between sqrt(x) and pow(x,0.5)

Tags: c++, c, sqrt

I was wondering why there is sqrt() function in C/c++ as we can achieve the same using

```
pow(x,0.5);
```

how is `sqrt(x)` different for `pow(x,0.5)` . Is there a specific reason of having sqrt function?

Comment: I do not think there is a special reason for that. As square root operation is very common and `sqrt(x)` improves the readability when compared to `pow()`.

Comment: why there is a bike when there is a bicycle?

Comment: Why do we have multiplication when you can just add in a loop?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This is a legit question!! It would be nice to know why sqrt performs way faster on my pc.

Comment: `sqrt` is a special case so naturally it can use much better approximations and optimizations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ran a test for you to check the performance of `sqrt(x)` and `pow(x,0.5)`

1.

```
for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++) 
    pow(double(i),0.5);
```

2.

```
for(int i=0;i<100000000;i++)
    sqrt(double(i));
```

1st one took around 20 seconds where as 2nd one took around 2 seconds on my computer. So performance is way better. As other have already mentioned readability is other reason.

Comment: I got the opposite results...

Comment: I actually ran the test 3 times just to make sure. I didn't get much of variation. Please check again.

Comment: [Test it](http://ideone.com/dlwLGR).

Comment: @SteveP.: Is that code compiled with -O3?

Comment: @steve P What processor are they using? The code which took more than 20 seconds on my PC ran in 0.6 seconds there. May be for larger values we can find the difference.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, if you're referring to optimizations made, I reversed the two segments and still got the same results.

Comment: @banarun no idea.  If they hadn't actually put this question on hold, I would've attempted to answer it based off of the source for the two...

Comment: @banarun try to reverse the two in your code on your computer and see what happens.

Comment: @Steve P I actually ran those two in separate programs

Comment: I think the pow function is optimised to sqrt() on ideone. when I compiled with -O3 there was no difference in the time taken for the two.

Comment: with -O3 and higher optimisations, benchmark such as yours will just get no-oped since no value is actually calculated... use int main() {
  double tot;
  clock_t t1;
   
  tot = 0.0;
  t1 = clock();
  for( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++ )
    tot += pow(double(i),-0.5);
  cout << "tot = " << tot << " time: " << clock()-t1 << "\n";
  
  tot = 0.0;
  t1 = clock();
  for( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++ )
    tot += 1.0 / sqrt((double)i);
  cout << "tot = " << tot << " time: " << clock()-t1 << "\n";
  return 0;
}

Comment: @banarun on the other hands, my results are consistent with your; sqrt is about 10x-20x faster on my machine, even with division added to sqrt...

Comment: AFAIK, many modern CPUs have hardware accelerated sin, cos and sqrt functions

Answer (score 6):

I remember reading somewhere that sqrt() is a special case that is guaranteed by the IEEE specification to be rounded correctly. I'll look that up to find a source. It should be a little faster too, because it only has to handle one case.

Even if they were the same, it's nice to have a builtin alias for a commonly used function!

Edit: According to the IEEE-754, both the pow() function and sqrt() are supposed to be implemented such that the rounded value is the closest possible floating point representation to the real value. However, sqrt() should still be faster.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259537/

Answer (score 5):

Sure, if you think of only the mathematical equivalence...

But in terms of algorithms to compute the result, `sqrt` is specific to one thing whereas `pow` is generic.

So you could (rightly) assume that it's possible to write a faster function for `sqrt` than it is to write the generic `pow` function.