# How do you do a power of 1/2 in C?

Tags: c

I just had a quick question in regards to do a power of 1/2 in C, I know about the pow function but I wish to do something else.

My goal is to make the following line into code where h is elevated to 0.5
R = -(g/2) + (h)½

I have tried 
r = (-(g/2) + (h*½));

but I doubt thats correct.

Comment: [`sqrt()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.7.5) from `<math.h>`?

Comment: `sqrt()` seems to offer some performance advantage over `pow` [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417490/difference-between-sqrtx-and-powx-0-5)]

Comment: @Maria as you could have guessed from the comments, this is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sqrt()` from `<math.h>`. The operation of H to the power of 0.5 is the [same](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/algebra/how-to-convert-square-roots-to-exponents/) as taking a square root of H. Use the inbuilt sqrt function to get a [performance advantage.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417490/difference-between-sqrtx-and-powx-0-5)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
   /*variable definitions*/
   r = (-(g/2) + sqrt(h));
   /*output*/
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: r = (-(g/2) + pow(h, 0.5)); Also does the job, but I like your approach too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know that if you try:

```
double x = 1/2;
printf("%f",x);
```

you will get a result of **0.0000**

Now for your equation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   double r,g,h;
   printf("Please enter g: \n");
   scanf("%lf", &g);
   printf("Please enter h: \n");
   scanf("%lf", &h);
   r = -1 * (g/2.0) + pow(h,0.5);
   printf("The result is %lf", r);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Your first point is valid — though an explanation of why (integer division) would be a good idea.  Your main answer seems to fly against the question commenting _'I know about the `pow` function but I wish to do something else'._